# Estimote Proximity Profile UUID for Android Development

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, android-bluetooth, proximitysensor, estimote

I'm trying to make an Android program that will always scan for a specific Bluetooth device, and alert the user when the phone is within proximity.

I modified the demo code provided here: https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGatt

The second demo here, (titled "BeaconActivity,") constantly scans for Bluetooth devices with the thermometer service.  For testing purposes, I am trying to make it scan for the proximity of an Estimote.  I do not want to use the provided Estimote SDK since I plan on using a more generic Bluetooth device in the future.

In the above "BecaonActivity" a UUID for the thermometer service is defined.  I tried switching this number out for the UUID for Estimotes defined on this page: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/200761958-Advertising-Packet-Estimote-s-Proximity-UUID

From the above linked source code, there is also a "TemperatureBeacon" class that has a "short-form UUID" of "0x1809."  I realized that this was just the 5th-8th character in the full thermometer service UUID, so I changed it to "0x7F30".

After mostly just changing the UUIDs and leaving most of the code the same, I tested it on my phone, but it could not detect the Estimote.  Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is Wojtek Borowicz, a community evangelist at Estimote. We're not ready yet to make specs for thermometer available for Android. Stay tuned!

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not trying to use the Estimote as a thermometer, I need to use it for its proximity detection, but without using the Estimote SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the demo code you provided but did you actually try to use the estimote proximty uuid (https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK) ?

```
private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
```

This might be helpful as well:
[Check if Bluetooth Low Energy Beacons are nearby in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823908/check-if-bluetooth-low-energy-beacons-are-nearby-in-android)
As David points out, for android devices you do not really have to consider UUIDs or services 
if you are only interrested in proximity.